# Spivak Calculus 4th Ed, Prologue, Problem 19a: what is the motivation behind the assumptions to this problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This question in Spivak seems to be about using algebraic manipulations to show the Schwarz Inequality.

Now, this is the Prologue so I am guessing the objective here is just to practice a bit with manipulating some expressions and maybe gaining some insight on some very basic derivations. However, in the case of this particular problem, I don't understand what the insight is.

Here is a picture of the relevant problem:

[image: Problem 19a]
[image: Problem 19a]

And here is the solution from the solutions manual.

[image: Solution to Problem 19a]

I am particularly interested in the last part of a), where it is assumed that there is no $\lambda$ such that $x_1=\lambda y_1$ or $x_2=\lambda y_2$. The problem gives you a quadratic in $\lambda$ to work with that is stated as larger than zero, so all you have to do is apply the formula $b^2-4ac<0$ to make determine the the relationship between the values of $x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2$ that make the quadratic inequality true. The relationship that you end up with is the given Schwarz Inequality.

**Question is: what is the deal with the assumptions on $\lambda$ here? I understand the work to get to the answer, but what is the motivation for this problem after all, with regards to starting with this setup of $\lambda$?**

By the way, here is what Problem 18 cited in Problem 19a looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spivak's statement of the inequality is the two-dimensional version of
$$\left|v\cdot w\right|^2\le(v\cdot v)(w\cdot w)$$
where $v$ and $w$ are vectors in a vector space and $\cdot$ is a dot product on that vector space. (For more on vector spaces, see e.g. [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space).) So, in two dimensions, if $v=(x_1,x_2)$ and $w=(y_1,y_2)$, their dot product is $x_1y_1+x_2y_2$, which we see in Spivak's problem. The condition with $\lambda$ has to do with whether $v$ and $w$ are parallel, so if that condition holds we can say $v=\lambda w$ giving the equality case, but otherwise we get a strict inequality. Viewing the givens $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ as vectors may help highlight how rare this equality case actually is: Spivak asks you to show that in every other case, so long as $v$ and $w$ are not parallel and neither is the zero vector, the inequality is strict.